# C++ ambiguous conversion type

Tags: c++

Supposing that the class obj has three constructors, default constrcutor and one using a string as a parameter and the other as an unsigned int.
Why do the compiler tells me that expression must have a class type for this case

```
obj A("1548"),B(19);
(A + "10").PrintMe();
```

and tells me for that case that the operator + has 4 overloads with a similar conversions

```
(A + 10).PrintMe();//even if i remove these overload he will turn the A into an int.
```

Also my class contain conversion operators like :

```
operator        int();
operator        double();
operator        unsigned int();
```

The only solution that works is :

```
(A + (obj)"99").PrintMe();
(A + (obj)99).PrintMe();
```

But i'd like the compiler do the work for me ..

---

simplified version of my class :

```
class obj: public mother
{
public:
    obj();
    obj(string);
    obj(unsigned int);
    obj(const obj &);
    ~obj();
    void PrintMe();
    obj operator=( obj);
    obj operator=(unsigned int );
    friend obj operator+(obj,obj);
    obj operator+=(obj);
    obj operator*(obj);
    obj operator*=(obj);
    operator int();
    operator double();
    operator unsigned int();
 }
```

Comment: Actual error message please

Comment: for (A + 10) you should return object..

Comment: for the second case Error 1 error C2666: 'operator +' : 4 overloads have similar conversions. for the first case it says Error 1 error C2228: left of '.printMe' must have class/struct/union

Comment: So (A + 10), all the conversion operators you have are valid, the compiler doesn't know which to pick.  C2228: left of '.printMe' is a "run on" error because of the previous problem.

Comment: show your overloads of `operator+` since `A + (obj)X` (`A.operator+((obj)X)` or `operator+(A, (obj)X)`) is not the same as `A + X` (`A.operator+(X)` or `operator+(A, X)`)

Comment: friend obj operator+(obj X,obj Y);

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: think it's using the conversion operators not an overloaded operator+()

Comment: How about: the whole code in a minimal sample and the error messages.  This is like pulling teeth.

Comment: @RichardCritten you're right. It was unclear to me.

Comment: Ok , i'm editing the question , sorry guys :)

Comment: you could make all the conversion functions `explicit`: `explicit operator int();`, they won't be considered in expressions like `A+5`